# Relocation advice? US TO UK (Aussie, Swedish, American family!)

Tags: relocation

Just looking for a little clarity, as the internet has us a tad confused. Thanks in advance :)

We are a family currently living in the US (both green card holders). I'm an Australian passport holder. My husband is an EU (Sweden) holder. Our son (2 years) US holder. We are relocating to England for personal reasons (not work) and are looking for clarity on requirements for Mother and Son (Aussie & US) to enter legally and Mum to work.

Firstly, am I right in understanding that none of us require visas to enter? And once in the country I (Aussie) can legally work due to husbands EU status? Are we missing something?

Thanks for your help in clarifying!

Nat :)

Comment: Worthy of note is that the US taxes green card holders worldwide, as it does its own citizens. Be aware that you will be required to file tax returns to the IRS and possibly pay some US tax.

Comment: @ScottEarle ...until they relinquish their permanent resident status.

Comment: @phoog it doesn’t say in the question that they were going to do that, but of course - if they are no longer green card holders, then that would no longer apply

Comment: @ScottEarle indeed.  I just wanted to point out that because of the tax considerations they might want to do it sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia says that your son [is a Swedish citizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_nationality_law), so the only document he needs is a Swedish passport or identity card.

You need to arrive before Brexit, or, if there is a transition period, before the end of the transition period.  The mother will have the right to work before Brexit, but will not realistically be able to prove that without a [residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card).  After Brexit, she will need [pre-settled status](https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families).

She can arrive without a visa, but she should be prepared to claim her right of free movement at passport control.  This means that she should have her marriage certificate with an apostille.  There are some other conditions that seem to be met here; see the EEA family permit link for details.

Another option is to get an [EEA family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit) before traveling, which will make the interview at the border considerably less stressful.

Comment: Wow, what a brilliantly helpful response! Thank you so much for your time!! We had no idea about the EEA family permit, wonderful to know that. Thanks so much  phoog :)

Comment: If the marriage certificate is Australian or American, it will be in English.  Will the OP still need an apostille.in that case?

Comment: @MartinBonner I don't see why not.  Apostilles are about authenticity, not language.